# The region bounded by $y=\sin x$, $y=\cos x$, $x=\pi/6$, $x=\pi/4$ is rotated about the $x$-axis; find the volume of the resulting solid.

Tags: volume, trigonometric-integrals

I’m stuck on this question.

> The area enclosed between the curves 
>   $$y=\sin x \quad \text{and} \quad y=\cos x $$
>   and within the lines $x=\pi/6 $ and $x=\pi/4$ is rotated about the x-axis. Find the volume 
>   of the solid of revolution formed.

I need some help with the steps to integrate and solve this.

---

The above is the second part of a question whose first part is simply to find the area of the region. I was able to solve that as follows:

Between $x=\pi/6$ and $x=\pi/4$ we have $\cos(x)>\sin(x)$. So the area is

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4} (\cos(x)-\sin(x))  dx &=[\sin(x)+\cos(x)]|_{π/6}^{π/4} \\
&=\sqrt{2}-\tfrac12-\tfrac12\sqrt{3}
\end{align}$$

This is what I found to be the enclosed area between these curves.

Comment: try to rewrite the body of the question because isn't readable

Comment: to that end, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, you can apply the washer method to integrate the revolving volume around $x$ as follows,

$$V=\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}\pi (\cos^2 x - \sin^2 x) dx$$

where the integrand represents the area of circular rings with outer radius $\cos x$ and inner radius $\sin x$. Carry out the integral to get

$$V=\pi\int_{\pi/6}^{\pi/4}\cos 2x dx= \frac{\pi}{4}(2-\sqrt{3})$$